# Right click to copy not functioning properly

Tags: vba, textbox, copy, controls, paste

I have a textbox which I would like to enable right click functionality on in order to copy.

I have the below code (thanks to the interweb), but although it shows the menu, nothing seems to make it to the clipboard.

In module 1:

```
Sub MakePopUp()
'Remove any old instance of MyPopUp
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars("MyPopUp").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

With CommandBars.Add(name:="MyPopUp", Position:=msoBarPopup)
    .Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=19
End With
End Sub
```

On my userform textbox:

```
Private Sub ResultsBox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As     Single, ByVal Y As Single)
MakePopUp
    If Button = 2 Then
    Application.CommandBars("MyPopUp").ShowPopup
End If
End Sub
```

Am I missing a piece here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're missing a small but pretty important piece. You never told the code what to do when you click the **`Copy`** menu item, so nothing happens as a result.

To address this, in `Module1` replace this line:

```
.Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=19
```

with this:

```
.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=19).OnAction = "Textbox_Copy"
```

Then, still in `Module1`, add the following Sub that implements the `Textbox_Copy` action that we referred to above. I'm assuming your userform is called `UserForm1`, so you should change the name if the name differs.

```
Public Sub Textbox_Copy()
  UserForm1.ResultsBox.Copy
End Sub
```

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. From a quick search of the interweb, if you want to get a better appreciation for this then you can take a look at the following:

- http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/383230-rightclick-context-menu-userform-textbox.html
- http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/07/using-copypaste-in-userforms/

The former is simple enough but the latter needs a bit more "skills" to understand.

The former is probably good enough for what you're doing and it implements additional operations like **`Cut`**, **`Paste`**, **`Select All`**, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fabulous resources!